# RUNTIME error in pthread_create with Qt program

Tags: c++, linux, qt, pthreads

I have a Qt program that uses the pthread library. It works well on Embedded Linux on ARM. However, the same program throws a runtime error on a Linux PC with a 64 bit Intel processor.

The point of failure is the line below:

```
err = pthread_create(tid++,&attributes,&threadFunction,NULL);
```

Return errno is 1. The runtime error thrown by stderror is:
"No such file or directory".

My project file (.pro) has the following related lines:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O2 -std=c++0x -pthread
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -O2 -std=gnu++0x -pthread
LIBS += -pthread
```

My Linux PC has pthread libraries installed, at the following locations:

```
/usr/lib/i686/nosegneg/libpthread.so.0
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

What am I missing? Any hints are very appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Qt, why use `pthreads` directly? Use `QThread` or even `std::thread` and let those libraries worry about it.

Comment: If the return value is 1, that would be EPERM, which means not sufficient permissions to apply the attributes (and not no such file or directory). What are your attributes?

Comment: @ cmannett85 Need pthread for C code that is part of the application.

Comment: @ Frank Osterfeld Thanks, that seems to be the reason. But the stderror message then seems to be wrong for the errno! Can you add an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @ddw: Probably errno isn't set at all? The way to get the error code seems to be the return value.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld That seems to be the issue. I have some legacy code that uses strerror(errno) if pthread_create returns a non zero value. That code is making a wrong assumption, apparently.